# Canonical quantisation: How to find the scalar product?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, field-theory, second-quantization

I am trying to understand the canonical quantisation procedure. I understood that one takes the classical field equation and replaces the field by an operator Φ which solves the field equations. Then one imposes the commutation relations on Φ and Π.

Since Φ solves the field equation one can write it as 
    Φ = Σ<sub>k</sub> u<sub>k</sub> a<sub>k</sub> + u<sub>k</sub><sup>*</sup> b<sub>k</sub>
.

where u<sub>k</sub> are solutions to the classical field equation and form a orthonormal basis. My question is now how to find the scalar product to which they are orthonormal? Is there a definite way how to find this scalar product? Or do I need to guess one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to your question is given by holomorphic quantization (a good treatment of which can be found in *Woodhouse, "Geometric Quantization", especially chapter 5 & section 9.2*<sup>1</sup>). The idea is that you can build a scalar product from two ingredients:

1. a [symplectic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space) $Ω$, which is a non-degenerate antisymmetric real-valued form, related to the Poisson brackets via:
   $$df = Ω(X_f,\,\cdot\,)$$
   $$\{f,g\} = d_{X_f} g$$
   (where $X_f$ denotes the Hamiltonian vector field generated by $f$): this you get for free from the commutation relations;
2. a [complex structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure)<sup>2</sup>, which is a (real-)linear operator $J$ on your phase space (seen as a *real* vector space) satisfying $J^2 = - \mathbf{1}$: given such a complex structure, any phase space can be turned into a *complex* vector space, defining the complex scalar multiplication by:
   $$\lambda u := \text{Re}(\lambda)\, u + \text{Im}(\lambda)\, J u.$$

If $J$ preserves the symplectic structure, i.e.
$$Ω(J\cdot,J\cdot) = Ω(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,),$$
then we can define a sesquilinear form by:
$$\langle u|v\rangle := 2Ω(u,Jv) + 2iΩ(u,v).$$

[To Be Continued...]

---

<sub>1 Woodhouse focuses mostly on finite-dimensional phase spaces, but he treats the more general case, namely [Kähler manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold), which requires extra integrability conditions on $Ω$ and $J$. The answer above only considers the linear case of phase spaces as "Kähler vector spaces", aka. Hilbert spaces.</sub>

<sub>2 A complex structure is a special case of what is called a *polarization* in the context of [geometric quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Take the lagrangian of the free spin zero complex particle:
$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu\Phi^*\partial^\mu\Phi-m\Phi^*\Phi$$
You can see that this lagrangian is $U(1)$ invariant:
$$\Phi(x)\to\Phi'(x)=e^{-i\theta}\Phi(x)$$
$$\Phi^*(x)\to\Phi^{*'}(x)=e^{+i\theta}\Phi^*(x)$$
Using the Noether theorem, this yield a conserved current as:
$$\delta\theta J^\mu=\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta(\partial_\mu\Phi)}\delta\Phi+\delta\Phi^*\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta(\partial_\mu\Phi^*)}=\partial^\mu\Phi^*(-i\delta\theta\Phi)+(i\delta\theta\Phi^*)\partial^\mu\Phi$$
equating the first and the last term:
$$J^\mu=i(\partial^\mu\Phi-\partial^\mu\Phi^*):=i\Phi^*\overleftrightarrow{\partial}\Phi$$
And there is also a conserved charge:
$$Q=\int d\vec{x}J^0=\int d\vec{x}\left(i\Phi^*\overleftrightarrow{\partial}\Phi\right)$$

And for the Klein-Gordon field, when you have its expansion in normal modes:
$$\phi(x)=\int d\vec{k}(f_\vec{k}\,u_\vec{k}(x)+f_\vec{k}^*u_\vec{k}(x)^*)$$
with
$$u_\vec{k}(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_\vec{k}}}e^{-i\omega_\vec{k}t+i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$$
these $u_\vec{k}(x)$ are orthonormal with respect to the hermitian product:
$$(u_\vec{k}(x),u_\vec{p}(x)):=\int d\vec{x}\left(iu_\vec{k}(x)^*\overleftrightarrow{\partial}u_\vec{p}(x)\right)\overbrace{=}^{\text{it can be checked}}\delta(\vec{k}-\vec{p})$$

Comment: but how do I find this conserved current for an arbitrary field (e.g. for the electromagnetic field)? And why, for example, do I not simply choose another conserved current for definition (I could take for example multiply the current by a constant.)?

Comment: You use the noether theorem since it is time-independent!

Comment: In fact, the conserved current has the property $\frac{dQ}{dt}=0$ from the fact that the current satisfies $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$. This time-independence is the key, since you don't want to have a scalar product which is time-dependent

Comment: Ok, but then how do I find (given some lagrangian) the symmetry group for the noether theorem. For example what is the symmetry group (or the conserved noether charge) for the electromagnetic field?

Comment: And in the case of the complex scalar. I could define a new noether charge $Q' = 4 Q$ which is also constant in time. But this would imply a different normalisation of the solutions and therefore yield to a different field operator.

Comment: You have to find the symmetry group of the given Lagrangian, taken a transformation you have to check whether $\mathcal{L}'=\mathcal{L}$. There isn't a general rule to find a simmetry of a given lagrangian. In Quantum field theory a requisite of every lagrangian is that they must be Poincaré-invariant and this leads to the energy-momentum tensor, and to the angular-momentum tensor conservarion.

Comment: And clearly you can choose a different Normalization, but nothing will change!

Comment: Poincare invariance only gives me energy, momentum and angular momentum. How do I know that there is an extra symmetry and if so, which symmetry should I use?

Comment: You write the Lagrangian and you have to search for the symmetry. But for the Klein-Gordon field it is the U(1) symmetry that is used to define the inner product.

Comment: I am pretty sure everything will change if you set $Q' = 4Q$: this implies $u_k' = 1/2 u_k$ and therefore $\phi(x)' = 1/2 \phi(x)$. If you then plug this into $[\phi(x)', \pi(y)'] = 1/4[\phi(x),\pi(y)] = 1/4 i \delta(x-y)$, so the CCR are not fulfilled anymore.

Comment: But what is the symmetry group for example for the electromagnetic field? It's a real field, so I cannot do complex transformations.

Comment: If you take the lagrangian of the electromagnetic field, it is $U(1)$ invariant.

Comment: This is the gauge invariance, but it only implies that charge is conserved. It does not tell anything about the propability.